# MongoDB - как лучше хранить диалоги с сообщениями

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Пока что есть три варианта. Ищу самый эффективный с точки зрения **производительности**

1. Коллекция, хранящае все сообщения со всех диалогов. Записи вида:

   `{ conv_id: 5; msg: "example"}`
2. Коллекция с именем - id диалога, содержащая сообщения только из своего диалога
3. Коллекция с диалогами вида:

   ```
   {
       conv_id: 5, #Ид диалога
       messages: [ 
           { msg: "msg1" },
           { msg: "msg2" }
       ]
   }
   ```

   (Не подходит из-за ограничения в 16МБ)

Comment: Первый вариант. Третий перпендикулярен производительности, второй забьет вам базу данных так, что вы не сможете в ней ориентироваться.

Comment: @Etki, спасибо за ответ. Интересно почему третий вариант медленнее третьего? MongoDB медленно работает со вложенными массивами? И еще - если использовать первый вариант - нужно ли индексировать поле conv_id?

Comment: Вставлю и свои 5 центов с: Индексировать нужно, и как уже прошедший через подобное рекомендую составлять id диалога из id собеседников